# Angular 2 | Firefox & Ms Edge - type error + docType error

Tags: angular, firefox, typescript, microsoft-edge, doctype

I'm building a Angular 2 app for different browsers. I got the latest versions of firefox, edge and Chrome. The angular app works perfectly on Chrome.

In firefox i get this error message:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

And this one too:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: result.subscribe is not a function.

Are there functions that I can not write in Typescript for Firefox?
And is there something like CanIUse but for angular 2 / typescript?

**fixed see Edit 1.
In Edge i cant even open the page, i get this error:

> HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: “”.

But i have a `<!DOCTYPE html>` in my index.html.

### EDIT 1 // 24-05

The Edge problem was due to 'localhost' i had to build a IIS webpage.

But now it still does not work.

I see all the JS code running without (alot) of errors, but i can not see anything on the page. All the HTML is loading in the DOM, but the screen stays empty. I get a warning that html tags are not recognized (but they are angular 2 tags..)

I think I should use the `<div app-view></div>` notation. Will try tomorrow.

### EDIT 2 // 09-06

found the solution a couple of days ago.

The api sent a XML back in Firefox in stead of a JSON object.

Added a ACCEPT header: Json and solved this. Chrome does this by itself, but firefox does not.

Hope it helps someone !

Comment: Maybe you have a UTF-8 [Byte Order Mark](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark) at the start of your HTML files which don't get handled correctly?

Comment: my html file starts with this: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>` so i dont think there is a byte order mark

Comment: You can give this a shot: http://www.larshaendler.com/2015/01/20/remove-bom-with-notepad/

Comment: no luck.. not working :(